# Probality of getting red ball in the fourth draw

Tags: probability

A bag contains $5$ distinct red, $4$ distinct green, and $3$ distinct black balls. If balls are drawn one by one without replacement, then what is the probability of getting **a particular** red ball in the fourth draw?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, so I solved two cases:

I. Here I supposed if you draw a red ball it counts as 1.

Of course only the fisrt four draw matters. Out of the 12 balls, you can draw the fisrt four in together $\binom{12}{4}=495$ ways. If the fourth draw is a red. The first free draw can be done by $\binom{11}{3}=132$ ways, hece the probability is $132/495$.

II. Here I supposed if you draw a red ball it counts 5.

Of course only the fisrt four draw matters. Out of the 12 balls, you can draw the fisrt four in together $12*11*10*9$ ways. If the fourth draw is a red, it can be chosen 5 ways. The first free draw can be done by $11*10*9!$ ways, hece the probability is $5/12$.